# JQuery Mask só funciona após submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou utilizando JQuery para adicionar máscara ao campo cpf quando o usuário for fazer uma pesquisa. No entanto a mascará só fica habilitada após fazer um submit na página (clicando no botão pesquisar).

```
<html>
<head>
    <title> </title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../style/scrpit.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../style/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../style/jquery.maskedinput.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#cpf").mask("999.999.999-99");
        });

    </script>
</head>

<body> 

 <div class="form-group col-md-5">                          
<input type="text" name="cpf" class="form-control" placeholder="CPF" id="cpf" required/>
 </div>


     <div class="form-group col-md-5">

      <button  type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" value="Pesquisar" name="Pesquisar">Pesquisar</button>

     </div>


    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Coloque `<script type="text/javascript" src="../style/scrpit.js"></script>` abaixo dos demais scripts ao invés de antes

Comment: Seu código está funcionando aqui: https://jsfiddle.net/mrlew/vm3r7k43/ . Deve ser algum outro problema. Qual o comportamento que você espera? Se o seu código vem de `scrpit.js`, e não da tag `<script>`, como você colocou, o problema pode ser a ordem de carregamento, como mencionado pelo @GuilhermeNascimento (mas isto não faria funcionar depois da submissão de formulário). Aliás, parece ser um erro de escrita ali (*typo*): `scrpit.js` não é `script.js`? De qualquer forma, este *snippet* apresentado na questão está funcionando.

Comment: @mrlew faz sentido, eu só disse para mover porque se ocorreu um erro de script poderia ser justamente por falha no script anterior, pois se fosse uma resposta eu teria respondido e não apenas comentado, resumindo é uma dica ;)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento sim, claro, por isto também comentei, pra ver se há mais algum esclarecimento, pois acredito que faltam elementos.

Comment: @mrlew Concordo plenamente ;)  e digo mais, nesses casos pode votar para fechar a pergunta como `Não clara` ou `Off-topic > Erro de digitação`

Comment: @mrlew realmente o problema era outro. No final do arquivo eu fazia chamada JQuery (script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js">). Isso que estava causando o problema. Acabei não inserindo este trecho de código na pergunta. Desculpem-me pela falta de atenção e obrigado pela ajuda. Quanto ao "scrpit" também já foi corrigido.